# Arduino code compile error: "lvalue required as left operand of assignment"

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, arduino

I am getting this error when I attempt to compile my code:

> lvalue required as left operand of assignment.

The code is reading in buttons though an analogue port. This is where the error is (in void(loop)):

```
while (count < 5){
    buttonPushed(analogPin) = tmp;

        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                while (tmp == 0) { tmp = buttonPushed(analogPin); }                 //something wrong with the first half of this line!

        if(sequence[j] == tmp){
                        count ++;
                }

        else { 
            lcd.setCursor(0, 1); lcd.print("Wrong! Next round:");                       delay(1000);
                        goto breakLoops;
                }

        }
}

breakLoops:
elapsedTime = millis() - startTime;
```

At the very top I have: `int tmp;`

Answer (score 2):

```
buttonPushed(analogPin) = tmp;
```

This line doesn't work. `buttonPushed` is a function and can only read from `analogPin`; you can't assign to the result of a function in C. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but I think you probably meant to use another variable instead.

Answer (score 2):

You have this line:

```
     buttonPushed(analogPin) = tmp;
```

You may want instead:

```
     tmp = buttonPushed(analogPin);
```

With the assignment operator, the object on the left of the `=` operator gets the value on the right of the `=` operator, and not the opposite.

Comment: Thanks very much Ouah. That seems to have worked perfect. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are trying to assign to a temporary / rvalue.  Assignment in C requires an lvalue.  I'm guessing the signature of your `buttonPushed` function is essentially the following

```
int buttonPushed(int pin);
```

Here the `buttonPushed` function is returning a copy of the found button which doesn't make sense to assign to.  In order to return the actual button vs. a copy you need to use a pointer.

```
int* buttonPushed(int pin);
```

Now you can make your assignment code the following

```
int* pTemp = buttonPushed(analogPin);
*pTemp = tmp;
```

Here the assignment is into a location which is an lvalue and will be legal

Comment: I don't believe `buttonPushed` returns any kind of `struct` because of this line: `tmp = buttonPushed(analogPin);` later on in the code. It may not be possible to modify its definition.

Comment: @minitech you're right, looks like more likely to be a numeric value